# How to upgrade node.js from 0.12 version to 4.0 version on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu

I already have installed Node.js v0.12.2 on Windows and Node.js v0.12.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Can I just run the latest installer to upgrade it to [v4.0.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/) on Windows and run `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu?

Comment: I have found the helpful instruction how to install the new node.js 4.0 manually https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debmanual

Answer (score 16):

Windows has an installer available at https://nodejs.org/en/download/

For Ubuntu, the official instructions are

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Find where `node` is

```
which node
```

Replace it with

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/nodejs /path/you/find/node
```

Comment: I tried this. It didn't update my node, rather installed a new one. `node -v` still showed 0.12. I had to remove it manually first.

Comment: @wsgeorge Even tho this "answer" didn't answer your question, you gave the one bit of info that seems to be missing from the web to "remove the previous version first". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for future use on Windows, you can take a look at [nvmw](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw/blob/master/README.md). Very easy to use and without manually modifying your configuration. When things break, you can just as easily switch back to older versions.

Similar package for Ubuntu: [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown)